# Check if object property has an assigned value

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have a class which allows for some properties to be left empty (null) problem is I don't know how to properly check for that and keep getting an error.

This is the class:

```
public class ZoomListItem
{
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string text1 { get; set; }
    public string text2 { get; set; }
    public ZoomAction action { get; set; }
}
```

and here is how I use the instance:

```
@foreach (ZoomListItem item in Model.templates)
{
    var actionUrl = (item.action != null) ? "" : "#";  //error here
```

The instantiation of the class has not assigned an action value, only text and image are given values. I get the following error in the line of the conditional:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null or empty

Am I not checking correctly with `item.action != null`?

Comment: and if you try to check if "item" is null??? Because at first sight, your code seems correct.

Comment: @Dryadwoods If item was NULL we´d get an NRE instead of the mentioned one. However, are you sure, you get the error at this line

Comment: Is `ZoomAction` a `struct` maybe?

Comment: `Value cannot be null or empty` and yet you set `actionUrl` to `""` - an empty string. I assume you're using `actionUrl` later in a place where empty strings aren't allowed, and the error isn't actually hapenning on the line you marked (it *can't* happen there - if you really are using auto-properties, that is).

Comment: @HimBromBeere: That is razor syntax. The @ basically says this is code and not stuff I want to appear on the page.

Comment: Occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll.  Look into the view model.  Put a try catch in there and get more detail.

Comment: The code was correct. The error was taking place in a later line and somehow the debugger pointed to the wrong line. Thanks for you answers and sorry for the wrong question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should check if `item.action` is null, but does not check if `item` is null. In the case that `item` is null, then a null reference exception will occur. You may want:

```
var actionURL = (item != null && item.action != null) ? "" : "#";
```

This will check `item` is not null first and then check `item.action` is not null.

@Luaan's comment looks like it contains the answer

Comment: @Dryadwoods Well, if this WOULD be the right answer, this approach posting this as answer would be absolutly fine, since you did not. However as William already mentioned, we´d get an NRE if `item` is null, so this IS NOT the right answer.